# Is it possible to convert the same to seaborn?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

```
 group = (df.groupby(['Attrition'])
   ['Department'].value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack('Attrition'))
print(group)

group.plot.bar(figsize=(20,5));
```

[image]

Can we convert the same to seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your (sample) data, I'm gonna have to draw in the dark here, but you can try:

```
group = (df.groupby(['Attrition'])
         ['Department'].value_counts(normalize=True)
         .reset_index(name='counts')
        )

sns.barplot(data=group, x='Department', y='counts', hue='Attrition')
```

Comment: Thanks, @Quang. It is what I was looking for. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is not to redo it in Seaborn but to change the style of matplotlib to use the Seaborn style with `sns.set`.

```
group = (df.groupby(['Attrition'])
   ['Department'].value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack('Attrition'))
print(group)

sns.set()
group.plot.bar(figsize=(20,5));
```